# How to find all upper case strings in a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, string, case-sensitive, uppercase

I initially thought this is trivial. Then thought 'binary' might do it. I am unsure at this point.

```
Name
----
John
MARY
Kin
TED
```

I would like to query just MARY and TED which are in all upper case. How would I query this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If your collation is case insensitive then you need to use a `BINARY` comparison:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE Name = BINARY UPPER(Name)
```

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea52e/1)

Comment: Binary is the key here! Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You just use the [UPPER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_upper) function on the `Name` field and compare the results with the original value of `Name`:

```
select Name from Table where Name = UPPER(Name)
```

This way

```
UPPER(Name)   ||  Name
---------------------------------------
JOHN          !=  John
MARY          ==  MARY
KIN           !=  Kin
TED           ==  TED
```

only the rows you need will be returned.

As @mdoyle commented here, you should define the column with the right collation (case sensitive), otherwise as others did answer you need the [BINARY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/cast-functions.html#operator_binary) operator to compare case insensitive columns.

Comment: Depends on the collation and data type.  If the data type is non-binary and the collation is, e.g., latin1, string comparisons will be case insensitive.  So I believe Mark Byers' answer is the most accurate so far.

Comment: Binary is essential in this case (atleast my case). Still upvoting for info.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select name from table where name=upper(name);
```

Comment: This only works with binary data types or the correct collation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT Name
FROM   table
WHERE  Name COLLATE latin1_general_cs LIKE UPPER(Name)
;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Below:

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE name = BINARY UPPER(column_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also return numeric values, but that doesnt look to be an issue for your column name.

```
SELECT * FROM names WHERE 

ASCII(name) = ASCII(Upper(name))
```

Comment: This only works with binary data types or the correct collation.