# sql: filter string results by uppercased

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a SQL query that returns a name and a id per row. The problem is that the name values, some are upper-cased and others are lower-cased. The query in question is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ttd.name, ttd.tid
FROM taxonomy_term_data ttd
INNER JOIN field_data_field_xxxxxx_paraules_clau fdfspc ON ttd.tid = fdfspc.field_xxxxxx_paraules_clau_tid
ORDER BY ttd.name
```

the result is something like:

```
alfred | 1
ALBERT | 2
MARIA  | 3
Sam    | 4
```

What I want is a WHERE clause to only get the rows with upper-cased name like:

```
WHERE ttd.name IS UPPERCASED
```

I have been searching on internet, but I only  get results about capitalize or uppercased text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check for uppercase letters in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16558967/how-to-check-for-uppercase-letters-in-mysql)

Comment: `WHERE ttd.name > 'A'`   might help  regex should work even better `WHERE ttd.name REGEXP '^[A-Z]+'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select ALL fields that contains only UPPERCASE letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836825/select-all-fields-that-contains-only-uppercase-letters)

Comment: There are some results that are Capitalized (first letter upercased), so the Raymond solution doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with the BINARY comparison and UPPER() in mysql

```
WHERE ttd.name = BINARY UPPER(ttd.name)
```

source : [How to find all upper case strings in a MySQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098649/how-to-find-all-upper-case-strings-in-a-mysql-table)

Comment: It worked! I tried without the binary and nothing. But like this works fine.